# Adding parameters to URLs from HTML file

Tags: php, html, url, preg-replace, file-put-contents

I'm creating a local php script to manipulate a HTML file exported from Photoshop. I need to add some parameters to every url . This is what I've tried:

```
$newHtmlFile = 'exported.html'; //HTML file exported from photoshop
$htmlContent = file_get_contents($newHtmlFile);

$randomQuery = 'utm_source=onlinenewsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_content=random&utm_campaign=test';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($htmlContent);
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $thisLink){
    $thisUrl = $thisLink->getAttribute('href');
    $parsedUrl = parse_url($thisUrl);
    if($parsedUrl['path'] == null){ $thisUrl .= '/'; }
    $separator = ($parsedUrl['query'] == NULL) ? '?' : '&';
    $newUrl = $thisUrl . $separator . $query;

    file_put_contents($newHtmlFile, preg_replace('~\b' .$thisUrl. '\b~u', $newUrl, file_get_contents($newHtmlFile)));
}
```

Example HTML exported from photoshop:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Some Page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
    <table id="Tabla_01" width="570" height="617" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="http://somepage.com/es/es/">
                    <img src="images/some_image_01.jpg" width="285" height="160" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
            <td>
                <a href="http://somepage.com/es/es/">
                    <img src="some_image_02.jpg" width="285" height="160" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

This throws no errors and it does not replace urls.

Comment: *This throws no errors* - Then please don't [suppress](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) errors, that may help.

Comment: write and reload file every iteration?????

Answer (score 0):

As I see you have same url in your html file,
its better to save them in their place instead of using `preg_replace`. you can use this:

```
$newHtmlFile = 'exported.html'; //HTML file exported from photoshop
$htmlContent = file_get_contents($newHtmlFile);

$randomQuery = 'utm_source=onlinenewsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_content=random&utm_campaign=test';

$dom = new DOMDocument;

@$dom->loadHTML($htmlContent);

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $thisLink){
    $thisUrl = $thisLink->getAttribute('href');
    $parsedUrl = parse_url($thisUrl);
    if($parsedUrl['path'] == null){ $thisUrl .= '/'; echo "here";}
    $separator = !isset($parsedUrl['query']) ? '?' : '&';
    $newUrl = $thisUrl . $separator . $randomQuery;

    //echo "$thisUrl - $newUrl <br/>";
    //file_put_contents($newHtmlFile, preg_replace('@' .$thisUrl. '@', $newUrl, file_get_contents($newHtmlFile)));
    $thisLink->setAttribute('href', $newUrl);
}

file_put_contents($newHtmlFile, $dom->saveHTML());
```